# Compile Qt5 qt-everywhere with QtWebEngine?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, compilation, configure

I got `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0.tar.gz` from [download.qt.io](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/single/). I unzipped it and ran:

```
> ./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -static \
    -no-sql-sqlite -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -openssl \
    -qt-xcb -nomake examples
> make -j4
> sudo make install
```

Everything succeeded. However, if I `ls /usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include`, I see no directory for `QtWebEngine`. Indeed, `find /usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/ | grep QWeb` yields:

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include/QtWebChannel/QWebChannelAbstractTransport
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include/QtWebChannel/QWebChannel
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include/QtWebSockets/QWebSocketServer
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include/QtWebSockets/QWebSocketCorsAuthenticator
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/include/QtWebSockets/QWebSocket
/usr/local/Qt-5.5.0/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5Gui_QWebpPlugin.cmake
```

That is, neither QWebEngine nor QWebKit. `grep QtWeb` likewise provides nothing relating to these two.

However, I know these are included in the `qt-everywhere` package - there's a `qtwebengine` directory as well as a `qtwebkit` directory. `ls qtwebengine/include` shows a `QtWebEngine` directory with the appropriate `QtWebEngine` include file.

How do I get qt to compile and install this? I have looked through `configure --help` to no avail. All I see is a `-skip <module>` flag, but nothing to force including qtwebengine.

Comment: The README says that `icu` is required for webkit to work. I passed the `-icu` flag specifically and it failed, saying they could not be built. After `sudo apt-get install libicu-dev`, the config passed, so I will try to rebuild and see if that works.

Comment: Dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085805/compile-qt5-qt-everywhere-with-qtwebengine) but it has no upvoted/accepted answer yet.